# Issue With Laravel Migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am currently trying to drop a foreign constraint from a table as I'm trying to improve the database normalization.

I'm trying to do this using laravel migrations, however I'm getting an error that and I can't see the cause of it.

This is the table that I'm trying to modify;

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| desc        | varchar(100)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| image       | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| supplier_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and supplier_id is the column that i'm trying to remove from this table.

This is the up method from the migration I'm using.

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
        \App\Subitem::truncate();
        Schema::table('subitems', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['supplier_id']);
            $table->dropColumn('supplier_id');
        });
    }
```

And this is my model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subitem extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','desc','image', 'status' ,'delivery_time','price'
    ];
}
```

Finally this is the error that laravel is throwing at me.

```
php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2020_11_02_082433_drop_columns_from_subitems_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'subitems_supplier_id_foreign'; check that column/key exists (SQL: alter table `subitems` drop foreign key `subitems_supplier_id_foreign`)

  at D:\Compras_TC\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'subitems_supplier_id_foreign'; check that column/key exists")
      D:\Compras_TC\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:131

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'subitems_supplier_id_foreign'; check that column/key exists")    
      D:\Compras_TC\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:129

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

What's hard to understand to me is the reason why laravel is looking for `subitems_supplier_id_foreign` instead of just `supplier_id`

Comment: If i check docs at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints i see that they enter the key name, not the column name into `$table->dropForeign()` i guess laravel is trying to guess the keyname based on your input, and got it wrong. If you check the keys in a db tool, you should see the key name you have to delete

Comment: The foreign key is named differently than the default name provided by laravel, so you may need to check the foreign key name before dropping it

Comment: what is your foreign key called? If you pass an array to `dropForeign`, so `$table->dropForeign(['supplier_id']);` Laravel will try to guess the foreign key name. If you pass a string, so `$table->dropForeign('supplier_id');` it will use the provided value as the foreign key name.